# Time zone based push notifications from Firebase not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to use the recipient time zone based push notifications but I can't get them to work.

As far as I understood from someone from Firebase, they are sent as data notifications on iOS and then scheduled as local notifications.

Currently, I have this code:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//

@import Firebase;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate>

@end
```

```m
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//

@import UserNotifications;

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {

    [FIRAnalytics handleOpenURL:url];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [FIRApp configure];

    if ([UNUserNotificationCenter class]) {
        [FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onFirebaseTokenRefresh:) name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];

    // ...

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler {

    [FIRAnalytics handleUserActivity:userActivity];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    [self connectToFirebase];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
}

- (void)onFirebaseTokenRefresh:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [self connectToFirebase];
}

- (void)connectToFirebase {

    NSString *firebaseToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];

    if (!firebaseToken) {
        return;
    }

    FIRMessaging *firebaseMessaging = [FIRMessaging messaging];

    [firebaseMessaging disconnect];

    [firebaseMessaging connectWithCompletion:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            return;
        }

        NSTimeInterval updatedAt = floor([NSDate date].timeIntervalSince1970);

        [FIRAnalytics setUserPropertyString:@(updatedAt).stringValue forName:@"UpdatedAt"];
    }];
}

#pragma mark - FIRMessagingDelegate

- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {}

@end
```

I also have swizzling disabled.

I have `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` too because I have to support iOS 7+.

1. Am I supposed to manually schedule the local notifications or does the Firebase SDK do this?
2. Are these "data notifications" compatible with iOS 7+?
3. What am I supposed to do in the "applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:" delegate method?
4. Is it necessary to enable any Background Mode Capability for the scheduled timezone notifications to work?

Comment: Hi, I recently met the same issue on User Notifications Framework. Did you find any solutions??

Comment: No, sorry. I didn't use Firebase after this.

Comment: What did you use?

Comment: @JCutting8, [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com).